# Querying foreing_key on a belongs_to association. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having trouble implementing a bookmark feature. I want to query all the techniques in the bookmark table matching the current user's id. The problem is I can't get the query to pull out the attributes of the actuall technique. I keep getting method "uid" missing

This is the controller with the query

```
def index 
 @technique = Bookmark.joins(:technique).where(user_id: current_user)
end
```

The Bookmark model

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :technique
end
```

The User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bookmarks
end
```

I am sure their is a problem with my query but I'm stuck.

Comment: Is `Technique` a model that `belongs_to: user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Bookmark.joins(:technique).where(user_id: current_user)`, you get a collection of `bookmarks`, not `techniques`.

If you want the `techniques`, you could do the following:

`Bookmark.joins(:technique).where(user_id: current_user.id).collect(&:technique)`

Answer (score 0):

The query throws an error because the `current_user` is not of the right type required in the `where` clause. You need to specify the current user's id. Also, your query would result in a collection of `:bookmarks` and not `techniques`.

A solution to this would be to execute the `joins` query and obtain the matched collection of techniques:

```
def index 
 @technique = Bookmark.joins(:technique).where(user_id: current_user.id).collect(&:technique)
end
```